# Добавить элемент в XML

Tags: xml, sql-server, xpath, запрос

Есть таблица, которая имеет поле с типом XML.
XML имеет следующий вид:

[image]

Необходимо добавить элемент `<Pr>1</Pr>` в тег `Person`, где или FIO или Date содержит в себе? или !(Могут находится в любых частях предложения).
Если `Person` не удовлетворяет условиям, то добавить `<Pr>1</Pr>`.
Подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант на примере переменной:

```
declare @Count int;
declare @XML xml = '
<root>
    <Personals>
        <Person>
            <pr>1</pr>
            <FIO>?.?. Герасимов</FIO>
            <Date>?</Date>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FIO>В.В. Некрасов</FIO>
            <Date>?</Date>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FIO>Тест?пм</FIO>
            <Date>?</Date>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FIO>В.В. Некрасов2</FIO>
            <Date>?</Date>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FIO>В.В. Некрасов1?</FIO>
            <Date>?</Date>
        </Person>
        <Person>
            <FIO>Тест?пм2</FIO>
            <Date>?</Date>
        </Person>
    </Personals>
</root>'

select @Count = max(@xml.value('count(/root/Personals/
                       Person[fn:contains(.,"?")][Date[fn:contains(.,"?")]][not(Pr)])', 'int'))

while @Count > 0 
begin
    set @xml.modify('insert (<Pr>1</Pr>) as first
                     into (/root/Personals/
                           Person[FIO[fn:contains(.,"?")]][Date[fn:contains(.,"?")]][not(Pr)])[1]')
  set @Count = @Count - 1
end

SELECT @xml
```

Comment: Вау. А какой это язык?

Comment: @VladD ну конкретно этот пример работает на MS SQL. [Вот приблизительное описание](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177454(v=sql.105).aspx)